# How to get .app file in an iOS Mac Catalyst App?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

is it possible to extract a `.app` file in Xcode of a mac catalyst iOS project? I want to put it into my applications folder.

If i archive and distribute it as development i only get a `.ipa` file for iPhones.

Mac Catalyst option is enabled in project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before archiving, you need to select "My Mac" in the destination menu (Product -> Destination -> My Mac). If the current selection is an iOS device it will archive the iOS version instead of macOS.